# How to prevent NERDTree buffer deletion? (or reload it)

Tags: vim, nerdtree

If I `:bd`at the NERDTree window, I cannot load it back by closing the NERDTree window and opening it back: it still comes empty.

How to solve this? Ideally I'd like to attribute no action to `:bd` in this buffer, but a proper reload shortcut would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing `:NERDTree` should reopen the buffer even after `:bd`. Perhaps some other setting is causing it to reopen empty?

If you want to disable `:bd` in the NERDTree buffer, use this `autocmd` in your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree cnoreabbrev <buffer> bd <nop>
```

Comment: The error occurs if you use `:NERDTreeToggle`. If you run `:NERDTree` after deleting the buffer the tree window will open and `:NERDTreeToggle` will again work.